# How to wait and get the status of web element using selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to check the status of `<td>` element which has status change from `"Running"` to `"Success"`. The status change might take around 1 minute or for every few seconds i need to retry checking the status of  element. Can someone help me how to achieve this , following is the html structure and snippet that i am trying.

Running

```
<tbody id="workflows">
<tr id="row8ff2244a64f3e7180164ff637c574d24" class="selected">
<td><span class="wf-status running" id="status8ff2244a64f3e7180164ff637c574d24">Running</span></td>
<td>Copy of Discovery v4madhu-test3-automate</td>
<td>03 Aug 16:14</td>
<td>autotest</td>
<td>dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Success

```
<tbody id="workflows">
<tr id="row8ff2244a64f3e7180164ff637c574d24" class="selected">
<td><span class="wf-status wfsuccess" id="status8ff2244a64f3e7180164ff637c574d24">Success</span></td>
<td>Copy of Discovery v4madhu-test3-automate</td>
<td>03 Aug 16:14</td>
<td>autotest</td>
<td>dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

sample code

```
timeout = 60
maxtime = time.time() + timeout
result = None
while result is "SUCCESS":
    try:
        # connect
        result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains,"dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net"] and td[contains,"Success"]/ancestor::tr')
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        if time.time() > maxtime:
            raise Exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply below solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

timeout = 60

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//tbody[@id="workflows"]//td[.="Success"]')))
```

This code should allow you to wait up to `60` seconds and return `True` once `td` with text `Success` appeared in DOM or `TimeoutException` in case no element appeared after 60 seconds passed

Comment: This, but I would use a css-selector instead of an xpath-selector to make the selector easier to handle and more readable. The OP uses xpath though, so I understand why you use xpath in the answer as well

Comment: CSS selector (in Selenium) does not allow you to locate element by its text content. If OP wants to wait for `"Success"` I thought it would better to use this selector. But there might be a lot of other options..

Comment: The td-element changes class from running to wfsuccess which imo is a more robust selector than looking at the text, but yeah I understand what you mean. The css-selector would be something like "td.wfsuccess", or even better "#status8ff2244a64f3e7180164ff637c574d24.wfsuccess" even though the ID looks auto-generated (which I consider a code smell)

Comment: @Andersson my td is unique (<td>dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net</td>
 )  for every tr . Can you please help with correct XPATH expression

Comment: The current code is working with single <tr> element in the table but when there are multiple tr elements .it will be better to differentiate based on <td>dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net</td>

Comment: `//tbody[@id="workflows"]//td[.="Success" and following-sibling::td[.="dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net"]]`

Comment: @Andersson . Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code  :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[contains,"dmatarget14.hpeswlab.net"] and td[contains,"Success"]/ancestor::tr'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate the status of the `<td>` element to change the text from **Running** to **Success** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `text_to_be_present_in_element` and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody#workflows>tr.selected>td>span.wf-status.wfsuccess"), "Success"))
  ```
- `text_to_be_present_in_element_value` and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody#workflows>tr.selected>td>span.wf-status.wfsuccess"), "Success"))
  ```